# How to create a php datetime object from this string

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I have datetime strings like these:

2015-02-13 22:00 GMT+1 -DST

2015-03-20 21:00 GMT-5 +DST

What I started to try:

```
<?php
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i ', '2015-03-20 21:00 GMT-5 +DST');
    echo $date->format('d-m-Y H:i');
?>
```

However I get stuck on the timezone and DST. I see on http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php that I can use `e, O, P and T` for timezone, but I don't understand which character is representing what. Could I even use it directly like this? Do I have to convert that -5 to e.g. -0500? Then what character? And what to do with DST?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That date string isn't common and has some unnecessary information in it (at the end). To parse it I just tell `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to ignore the `GMT` and `+DST` parts by using the `+` character. The `O` character is smart enough to handle `-5` and convert it to `-0500`. If we don't ignore them the timezone is incorrect in the new DateTime object.

```
<?php
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i +O +', '2015-03-20 21:00 GMT-5 +DST');
    echo $date->format('d-m-Y H:i');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/291853)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to be getting the timezone right: https://eval.in/291852 - It does work like this: https://eval.in/291854 but then I have to remove the dst.

Comment: Yep :) I wanted to be sure that timezone was correct in case it mattered to your project.

Comment: Thanks :) now I can just use the full original string.

Answer (score 1):

I found this at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.
And yes I believe you can use it directly.

> e - Timezone identifier (added in PHP 5.1.0) Examples: UTC, GMT,
>   Atlantic/Azores
>
> O - Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) in hours   Example: +0200
>
> P - Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) with colon between hours and
>   minutes (added in PHP 5.1.3)  Example: +02:00
>
> T - Timezone abbreviation     Examples: EST, MDT ...